# How to get memory usage per target

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have been working together with Prometheus and Grafana where I am trying to integrate them both together. My problem currently is that my node exporter is currently redirecting to port 9100 which I was able to do:

[image: Total]

However this would just sum up the whole computer status but what I want to do is that I would like to get RAM usage of each target:

```
# Sample config for Prometheus.

global:
  scrape_interval:     1s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 1s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).

  # Attach these labels to any time series or alerts when communicating with
  # external systems (federation, remote storage, Alertmanager).
  external_labels:
      monitor: 'example'

# Alertmanager configuration
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:9093']

# Load rules once and periodically evaluate them according to the global 'evaluation_interval'.
rule_files:
  # - "first_rules.yml"
  # - "second_rules.yml"

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  
  - job_name: node
    # If prometheus-node-exporter is installed, grab stats about the local
    # machine by default.
    static_configs:
      - targets: [
                  'localhost:8000',
                  'localhost:8001',
                  'localhost:8002',
                  'localhost:8003',
                  'localhost:8004',
                  'localhost:8005',
                  'localhost:8006',
                  'localhost:8007',
                  'localhost:8008',
                  'localhost:8009',
                  'localhost:8010',
                  'localhost:8011',
                  'localhost:8012',
                  'localhost:8013',
                  'localhost:8014',
                  'localhost:8015',
                  'localhost:8016',
                  'localhost:8002',
                  'localhost:8017',
                  'localhost:8018',
                  'localhost:8019',
                  'localhost:8020',
                  'localhost:8021',
                  'localhost:8022',
                  'localhost:8023',
                  'localhost:8024',
                  'localhost:8025',
                  'localhost:8026',
                  'localhost:8027',
                  'localhost:8028',
                  'localhost:8029',
                  'localhost:8030',
                  'localhost:8030',
                  'localhost:8031',
                  'localhost:8032',
                  'localhost:8033',
                  'localhost:8034',
                  'localhost:8035',
                  'localhost:8036',
                  'localhost:8037',
                  'localhost:8038',
                  'localhost:8039',
                  'localhost:8040',
                  'localhost:9100'
                ]
```

and now I am stuck where I do not know how or if its even possible to get the RAM usage that is being used by the different ports?

The output I would like to do is:

[image: Output]

EDIT:

How to run one node exporter for each node and use the instance label to differentiate between the different nodes/computers?

Comment: Your scrape config is referencing multiple node exporters running on a single computer (localhost). You should specify the host names/ip addresses for each of the computers you want to monitor or else you will be duplicating the metrics because you are scraping for a single computer multiple times. There is an instance label that you can use to filter/group your visualizations to give you the metrics for each node/computer that you are monitoring.

Comment: Hi @BrandonMcClure - Right but how would that be possible to do that if I might ask? If its even possible to do it ??

Comment: are you asking if it is possible to have multiple node_exporters running on a single instance (node/computer) and get some subset of metrics from each the answer is no. You should only run 1 node_exporter for each node and use the instance label to differentiate between the different nodes/computers. I think it would be helpful for you to edit your question with what specifically you are trying to achieve by running multiple node_exporters on a single computer.

Comment: Hi @BrandonMcClure I have now updated my question at the very bottom. I was unsure how it worked until you explained. But i am not sure how I can add instance label for each port. Basically if it make sense... I have e.g. 5 py scripts that I am running that we can call main1.py main2.py mainN.py - each py file has its own port when starting the script (port 8000, 8001, 8002 ...) and I want to be able to get the RAM USAGE/CPU USAGE for each script rather than the total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping this part for historical purposes:
*By default your metric series when scraped are given labels. The minimum is a `job` and an `instance`.
For example if your metric series is `node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes`
You could select the series from one of your targets as
`node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes{instance="localhost:9100"}`
This applies to metrics of any type.
Side note: If you have multiple node_exporter running on your server, you won't see different information.*

Edit:

The stated issue is that @ProtractorNewbie wants to be able to export the CPU usage from single server. Ideally they wanted to use node_exporter.

Today there is not a way for `node_exporter` to provide process by process information.

However, a possibility would be use [`collectd`](https://github.com/collectd/collectd) with the `cgroups` and `write_prometheus` plugins configured and enabled.

Then you would need to have each of those services [running as systemd services](https://medium.com/@benmorel/creating-a-linux-service-with-systemd-611b5c8b91d6).

The data which you'd want to use will look like:

```
collectd_cgroups_cpu_total{cgroups="myservice.service",type="user",instance="myinstancename"} 0 1632740881417
```

From there you can do any of the typical prometheus operations.

Comment: Hello! so example if I have set in my python to connect to port 8000 prometheus. You mean that if I change the instance to 8000 then it would show the CPU/RAM specific for only that port?

Comment: If the answer is yes then it does not seems like it is working as it returns no data for me :/

Comment: I have now updated my question as well, see at the very bottom :)

Comment: I see so this is more of a question about how to expose the cpu usage of each process running on the server.

Comment: @ProtractorNewbie I have updated my answer to more accurately reflect things.